# Round corners of WebView widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using [Flutter's WebView plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter).

I tried wrapping WebView inside the `ClipRRect` widget to round the corners of the WebView, but the WebView remains rectangular with sharp corners instead of rounded corners.

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        const Radius.circular(8.0),
      ),
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl: "https://flutter.io"
      ),
    )
```

Is there a way to round the corners?

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you provide a screenshot? Or maybe a full reproducible sample code?

Comment: Turns out Flutter can't do clipping on iOS native views https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25965

Comment: oh, that explains it. I was testing on Android.